# How to calculate the Integral with confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, generating-functions, hypergeometric-functions

How to prove this.Thank you in advance
Let $\delta,\beta>0$ How to prove this
\begin{align}
& \int^1_0 \frac{w^{1-\beta}}{(1-w)^{1+\delta}} (-t.s w)^{\frac{-\delta}{2}} e^{-\frac{w}{1-w}(s+t)}J_\delta \left(\frac{(-t.s w)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-w} \right) \, dw \\[8pt] & = \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\delta+1)}\Phi(\beta,\delta+1,s)\Psi(\beta,\delta+1,s)
\end{align}
where  $J_\delta$ is the  Bessel function and
\begin{align}
\Psi(\alpha, \gamma ; z) = {} & \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty e^{-z t} t^{\alpha-1}(1+t)^{\gamma-\alpha-1} d t \\[6pt]
& [\operatorname{Re} \alpha>0, \quad \operatorname{Re} z>0]
\end{align}
with
$$
\Phi(\alpha, \gamma ; z)=\frac{2^{1-\gamma} e^{\frac{1}{2} z}}{\operatorname{B}(\alpha, \gamma-\alpha)} \int_{-1}^1(1-t)^{\gamma-\alpha-1}(1+t)^{\alpha-1} e^{\frac{1}{2} z t} \, dt
$$